# How to create a one-to-one mapping from 3 digits to 3 completely different digits (base 10)?

Tags: algorithm, mapping

How to create a one-to-one mapping from 3 digits to 3 completely different digits (base 10)?

Order matters. The given string has distinct digits.

For example, given `012`, receive `345`. The resultant string cannot contain a digit from the original. Mapping should be one-to-one for all `10 * 9 * 8 = 720` possibilities.

The few mathematical ideas I had, such as adding to or subtracting from the digits, all seem to allow for a digit to be repeated.

Comment: Why not ROT5? I.e., replace every digit D with ((D + x) mod 10)?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I think what you mean is that each 3-digit string can potentially be mapped to/paired with 210 different strings.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Consider `045`. If I understand correctly, ROT5 will produce `590`, in which case `0` and `5` will be repeated. One of my conditions is that no digits from the original string appear in the resultant string.

Comment: Drunk SO-ing -- not necessarily a good approach to gaining fabulous reputation and admiration. Hic.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Happy Halloween.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the minimum k such that adding k to each digit mod 10 results in a disjoint set of digits. Do that. The inverse operation is subtracting the same k from each digit mod 10.

Proof sketch of correctness: all arithmetic operations are mod 10. The first observation is that there always exists a suitable k. There are 10 choices of k but only 9 possible conflicts, where a conflict consists of a position in the input and a position in the output that hold the same digit. Each conflict is triggered by exactly one choice of k. The second observation is that, given an input (a, b, c), the value of k is invariant across inputs (a + d, b + d, c + d) where d is a digit. It follows that the inverse operation truly is the inverse (because the value of k is determined to be the same) and hence that both operations are bijections.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do you mean that each 3-digit string will have a different k?

Comment: I wouldn't be averse to learning about/from your proof, although it is not a must.

Comment: @גלעדברקן I added a sketch.